# Unable to send files to server with http package

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am trying to upload files to server, and I get 200 for response status code, but the files were not sent successfully and I do not get them in the desired screen.
This is my function:

```
 Future _selectFileToUpload() async {
  try {
  FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform
      .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, type: FileType.any);
  if (result != null) {
    setState(() {
      result.files.forEach((selectedFile) async {
        File file = File(selectedFile.path);

        var uri = Uri.parse(
            'myUrl');

        var length = await file.length();
        dynamic stream = http.ByteStream(file.openRead());

        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        };

        var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

        var multipartFileSign = new http.MultipartFile(
            'jpg', stream, length,
            filename: selectedFile.path);

        request.files.add(multipartFileSign);

        request.headers.addAll(headers);

        request.fields['documents[attachments_attributes]'] =
            base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());

        var response = await request.send();

        print(response.statusCode);
        response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
          print(value);
        });
        });
        });
        } else {
       print("User has cancelled the selection");
      }
  } catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Response status code is 200

When I print value get {"data":[]}

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use to upload image files to server.

```
  static Future upload(BuildContext context, url, File file)  async {

    _context = context;

    var ur = Constants.BASE + url;

    // open a bytestream
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(file.openRead());
    // get file length
    var length = await file.length();

    // string to uri
    var uri = Uri.parse(ur);

    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    // multipart that takes file
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length, filename: file.path);

    Map headers = {
      'token': 'YOUR TOKEN OR YOUR HEADERS HERE'
    };

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    // add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    // send
    var response = await request.send();

    // I wait a file id from server, not for you if you don't wait for anything from server
    var fileId = await http.Response.fromStream(response);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return fileId.body;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Download

```
  static Future download(BuildContext context, String id) async {

    _context = context;
    var ur = 'Constants.BASE$id';

    try {
      var response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(url),
          headers: headers(),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(response.bodyBytes);
        return bytes;
      } else {
        print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}. ${response.bodyBytes}');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Download error: $e');

      return null;
    }

  }
```

It seems your code is good as well, maybe you should check server side also.